# Draw line on top side of binary mask using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, line, contour

I have a binary mask. In the binary image, I always have this mask which goes as horizontal band. I can use cv2.findContours() to find the boundary around the mask but I am only interested in the **top line of mask** as shown in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZm1a.png (The line is hand drawn so it is not perfect). My question specifically is how to just draw the top line and not the lower part.

Using: OpenCV and Python

Comment: Post your original binary mask without andy markings.  You could do an 8-bit vertical sobel filter directed to find a step from black to white only. That should get the top of the white band.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to detect both top and bottom parts of the object you want to detect, you can know which line is at the top by looking at their pixel position. You could apply a morphological gradient and `cv2.connectedComponents()` to have the two borders detected and then average their pixel positions to know which border is more at the top.

I do not know if your problem is in drawing the straight lines too, but I think it should be easy having the two points (left and right axis crossings) and then using `cv2.line(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)` in which the `start_point` and `end_point` are the limits of the top part of the mask.

If you post the original image, it should help even more.

Hope it works.